# Find MySql concurrent user per hour in a week

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my table, i want to find concurrent user per hour for a given week

I am trying to calculate number of concurrent users in a time range. The input looks something like the below

## Table

```sql
id  user_id  login_time
1    23     2016-06-08 09:10:00
2    24     2016-06-08 08:55:00
3    25     2016-06-08 09:29:00
4    26     2016-06-08 09:40:00
5    27     2016-06-08 09:08:00
6    28     2016-06-09 13:40:00
7    31     2016-06-09 14:04:00
```

How to get the concurrent users in time range ?

Expected Output Table

| Date | Hour | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-08-04 | 0 | 3 |
| 2014-08-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 2014-08-04 | 2 | 0 |
| 2014-08-05 | 0 | 1 |

Similar question
[concurrent users sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588899/concurrent-users-sql)

Comment: Please post data as text not images. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you also store logout times?

Comment: @circo No, only login time. We can assume user logout time is 1 hour after login time.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: the link to "concurrent users sql" is to an article with tags: `mysql` ?

Comment: @Luuk It says MySQL. I have tried the solution but its not working. Can you have a look. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1707838

Comment: You can do this in SQL but for me, without logout time this has no sense at all

Comment: The sqlfiddle you posted in the comments is for MySQL 5.6. which version are you using?

Comment: @Luuk I am new to SQL. Just checked version and got to know its 5.6 and WITH clause doesn't work for this version. Anyway thanks for your answers and support

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with this, but (from my opinion) it has no sense the result you are trying to get because you need to calculate the time:

- If a user enters 9:30 and left 9:35 and re-enter 9:45 is not a concurrent user but you get this in the SQL.
- If a user enters 9:59 and enter 10:01 you have a concurrent user but you won't see this with this logic of "hour"
- Concurrent user with different day (23:59 and 00:01 logins)

In any case, the SQL you are asking for:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16a39/9/0)
SELECT
up.user_id,
up.diff as TimeDiff,
FROM
(
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,u1.login,u2.login) as diff, u1.user_id FROM users u1
JOIN users u2
ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
AND u1.login < u2.login ) up
WHERE up.diff < 1

And without DIFF time (as you requested):

```
SELECT 
g.id,
g.hour,
g.datelogin,
COUNT(*) as times
FROM
(SELECT HOUR(login) as hour, DATE(login) as datelogin, id FROM users) g
GROUP BY datelogin, hour, id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- This will show only counts is bigger than 1
```

Comment: @Abbad sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Could you comment a link with data more real in order to check your problem? For example, with data that you will get as result

Comment: @Abbad Please check my update: I update the query but also your data because there was no user with concurrent result in your fiddle to show the example. I remove the GROUP for clarification.

Comment: @Abbad the fiddle is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=671b5493b08fd6d0eebef6a24b4344e0)

- first I entered the data from your question
- half-way I changed data to what was given here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67356f/2
- first the `cte1` contains the first and last date from `users`.
- `cte2` contains all the dates between `StartDate` and `EndDate`
- `cte3` contains all (24) hours for the dates.
- After this is is just counting to see if a user is logged in.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (
   SELECT 
      DATE(MIN(login_time)) StartDate,
      DATE(MAX(login_time)) EndDate
FROm users),
cte2 AS (
   SELECT cte1.StartDate
   from cte1
   union all
   select DATE_ADD(cte2.StartDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   from cte2
   cross join cte1 where cte2.StartDate < cte1.EndDate
),
cte3 AS (
   SELECT StartDate, 0 as H
   FROM cte2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT StartDate, H+1 FROM cte3 WHERE H<24
)
select * from (
   select 
      StartDate as `Date`,
      H as `hour`,
      (SELECT count(*) from users 
       WHERE login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(StartDate, interval H HOUR) AND DATE_ADD(StartDate, interval (H+1) HOUR)
      ) as `Count`
   from cte3) x
where x.`Count` <>0
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: How to convert this to MySQL5.6 is explained in  this Question + Answer: [How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)